# The underlying connection was closed: The connection was closed unexpectedly. when i try to download Some Websites html code

Tags: c#, web-scraping

```
private string DownloadHtml(string address)
        {
            string result = "https://potnhub.com";
            ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
            //ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = (SecurityProtocolType)768 | (SecurityProtocolType)3072;
            WebRequest wrq = WebRequest.Create(address);
            Stream Mystream = wrq.GetResponse().GetResponseStream();
            byte[] buffer = new byte[256];
            int Readed = 0;
            do
            {
                Readed = Mystream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                result += Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer, 0, Readed);
            } while (Readed!=0);
            Mystream.Close();
            return result;
        }
```

I want to download HTML code from sites like pornhub or tiktok or youtube
this code is working for normal sites, and it works for youtube too with vpn but for pornhub and tiktok i get the error

> The underlying connection was closed: The connection was closed unexpectedly

Screenshot [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cfNrW.jpg)

I also use Psiphon VPN and that is because the country that I live in blocks sites like youtube etc.

at first i thought it was because of the vpn so i used other vpn but i got the same result

Answer (score 0):

You can do this very easily using HttpClient

```c
    public static async Task<string> DownloadHtml()
    {
        using var client = new HttpClient();
        HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("https://www.google.com");
        return await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    }
```

As for why your code isnt working, Id assume its likely due to an invalid URL being used

Comment: not working on pornhub or tiktok